# How to access the variables defined in Livewire component in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

There is an existing Livewire component and its corresponding blade file in the code structure.I want to create a new Laravel Controller and blade file.The blade files include variables that are defined in the Livewire component so when I return the newly created blade file from the new Laravel controller it shows undefined variable error.Is there any way to pass the variables defined in Livewire component in the newly created blade file?Also is there any alternative to this approach?

This is the blade file and the variable.

```
@if($variable)

@endif
```

This variable is defined the livewire component.

```
public $variable=false;
```

And the newly created controller is returning the above mentioned blade file.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't give you any definite answer because no code was posted and I don't know what your aim is

But if you really do need to pass variables to the new blade file, you can look into livewire browser events
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events

You can dispatch a browser event in the child component and listen for it in the parent

I once did this in a project of mine

```
 ​$​this​->​dispatchBrowserEvent​(​'nationality-updated'​,[​'nationality'​ => ​$​this​->​nationality​]); 
 ​​$​this​->​dispatchBrowserEvent​(​'state-updated'​,[​'state'​ => ​$​this​->​state​]);
```

And I listened to it in a parent component like this

```
<​script​> 
 ​​window​.​addEventListener​(​'​nationality-updated​'​,​event​ ​=>​ { 
 ​ ​@this​.​set​(​'​state.nationality​'​, ​event​.​detail​.​nationality​) 
 ​}) 
 ​window​.​addEventListener​(​'​state-updated​'​,​event​ ​=>​ { 
 ​​@this​.​set​(​'​state.state​'​, ​event​.​detail​.​state​) 
 ​   }) 
 </​script​>
```

Note that state.nationality is a livewire variable I accessed from Javascript and I'm not quite sure if that is optimal

But if you must you can follow the above